# How to clear a module mock between tests in same test suite in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I've mocked some nodejs modules (one of them, for example, is `fs`). I have them  in a `__mocks__` folder (same level als `node_modules`) folder and the module mocking works. However, whichever "between test clearing" option I use, the next test is not "sandboxed". What is going wrong here?

A very simplified example of the mocked `fs` module is:

```
// __mocks__/fs.js
module.exports = {
    existsSync: jest.fn()
        .mockReturnValueOnce(1)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(2)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(3) 
}
```

I'm simply expecting that in every test, whenever `init()` is called (see below), `existsSync` starts again at value 1: the first value of `jest.fn().mockReturnValue()`. In the testfile I have the following structure:

```
// init.test.js
const init = require("../init");
const { existsSync } = require("fs");
jest.mock("fs");

describe("initializes script", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // see below!
    });    

    test("it checks for a package.json in current directory", () => {
        init();
    });

    test("it stops script if there's a package.json in dir", () => {
        init(); // should be run in clean environment!
    });
}
```

And once again very simplified, the init.js file

```
const { existsSync } = require("fs");
console.log("value of mocked response : ", existsSync())
```

I'm getting the following results for `existsSync()` after the first and second run of`init()` respectively when I run in `afterEach()`:

- jest.resetModules() : `1`, `2`
- existsSync.mockReset(): `1`, `undefined`
- existsSync.mockClear(): `1`, `2`
- existsSync.mockRestore(): `1`, `undefined`

Somebody know what I'am doing wrong? How do I clear module mock between tests in the same suite? I'll glady clarify if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reset the modules and require them again for each test:

```
describe("initializes script", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules() 
    });    

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock("fs");
    })

    test("it checks for a package.json in current directory", () => {
        const init = require("../init");
        init();
    });

    test("it stops script if there's a package.json in dir", () => {
        const init = require("../init");
        init();
    });
}
```

Comment: Aren't jest mock calls hoisted (in most cases)? The implication being even if you nest jest.mock in a beforeEach, the mock runs before the file. ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: It is possible I was using and older version since they [released a new major one the same year making it hoist mocks by default](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blame/48cda778b285d32e47b3a1bae0f64fffe6601ce0/CHANGELOG.md#L2657), that code did work but you are right, it won't on newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the solution above. I managed to solve the issue with the next snippet.

```js
afterEach(() => {
  Object.keys(mockedModule).forEach(method => mockedModule[method].mockReset())
})
```

I would prefer to have a native method doing this though. Something like `mockedModule.mockReset()`.

Comment: What is "`mockedModule `"? Is that a variable you assign to from within all of your tests? More description would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

For local variables, the scope of declaration is important.

```js
const mockFunc1 = jest.fn() // possibly bad mock reset/clear between tests
describe('useGetMetaData', () => {
  const mockFunc2 = jest.fn() // good mock reset/clear between tests

  afterEach(() => {/* reset/clear mocks */})

  test.todo('implement tests here')
})
```